# RSpec install error: "Could not find autotest in any of your source paths"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, installation

When I run:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

I get this output:

```
   identical  .rspec
       exist  spec
   identical  spec/spec_helper.rb
Could not find "autotest" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
(..)/rails_projects/sample_app/lib/templates/rspec/install
(..)/rspec-rails-2.3.0/lib/generators/rspec/install/templates
```

I'm new to RSpec, Rails and Ruby. Any tips on how to make this work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bug. It can be circumvented:

"A quick solution for those with this problem is to make the missing directory in the gem. (i.e., mkdir rspec-rails-2.3.0/lib/generators/rspec/install/templates/autotest )"

Ref:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/closed#issue/283

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the other day.  The only thing that solved it was to uninstall the autotest and rspec gems and re-install them.